# Confusion between url_for and host definition for ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Rails mailer instances do not have any context about the request.  However this is needed to service multiple hosts.  I was hoping to invoke [url_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html) for the mailer, but I am confused to **both** the placing of it AND how it should be constructed (the api documentation provides examples for controllers, not mailers).

The form submission has a hidden_field  `:host, value: @site.host`  which percolates to the request

```
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"email"=>"some@quack.com", "host"=>"localhost"}
```

`environments/development.rb` has `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` commented out.
initializer for devise has `config.parent_mailer = 'DeviseMailer'`
The users/passwords_controller.rb has been edited

```
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
   def create
puts params[:host]
     super
   end
```

and mailers/devise_mailer.rb  sets

```
class DeviseMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  layout 'mailer'
  before_action :set_mailers_url_host

  def set_mailers_url_host
puts 'host'
puts params
    ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = params[:user][:host]
  end
```

I did not expect the mailer to know the parameter as it is designed to inherit from  `< ActionMailer::Base`
However, the log is indicating that the password controller generated is not being invoked. the 'host' string is being put, then an empty line indicates the mailer know nothing of the params

```
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#create as HTML
[...]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:284:in `get_departments'
  User Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "users"...
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "users"...
  TRANSACTION (1.0ms)  BEGIN
  User Update (1.7ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "reset_password_token" = $1, "reset_password_sent_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["reset_password_token", "..."], ["reset_password_sent_at", "..."], ["id", 45]]
  TRANSACTION (6.1ms)  COMMIT
host

Devise::Mailer#reset_password_instructions: processed outbound mail in 0.6ms
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 745ms (ActiveRecord: 81.6ms | Allocations: 203970)
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):

app/mailers/devise_mailer.rb:8:in `set_mailers_url_host'
```

The error is expected given `params[:user][:host]` is an unknown entity to the mailer. The bypassing of the passwords controller, not.

Also attempted:  commenting out the devise_mailer before_action and adding to the application_controller.rb, where @site is set in `before_action :set_site` :

```
  def default_url_options
    { host: @site.host, locale: I18n.locale }
  end
```

While this is the most succinct way of dealing with the case,  that fails with error `ActionView::Template::Error (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true)`

Why are the checks (via `puts`) in the passwords controller not being invoked?
How should url_for thus establish the required string based on `params[:user][:site]`

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to solve your issue but I'm not quite satisfied with the beauty of this.

```rb
around_action :change_host

def change_host
  default_options = Rails.application.routes.default_url_options
  new_options = { host: param[:user][:host], port: :thing }
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = new_options
  Rails.application.configuration.action_mailer.default_url_options = new_options

  yield

  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = default_options
  Rails.application.configuration.action_mailer.default_url_options = default_options

end
```

Comment: That cannot work, as the host is a dynamic value based on the request which must "service multiple hosts".  the environment file in production would be loaded at start-up and be static.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood your question. I've updated my answer. 

Comment: and you would place that in the relative environment configuration file?  how do you pass the param[:user][:host]  or instance variable then?

Comment: I would place that directly on the controller or the mailer definition main class (using inheritance to DRY).

Comment: You were worried about the `beauty` of the solution. The other solution here is three one-line steps, no callbacks.

Comment: I would say so. I'm not satisfied enough but I don't see other way to solve your problem.  
The last thing I have in mind is to create your own helper but if you do so, please add some spec with it. 
Here is the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a217fd0d1392e2ab53d86682a52cc40330e6089f/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb#L166) for some inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Given all the moving parts, a quick review:

- comment out config.action_mailer.default_url_options
- submission of param in form for host
- no need for DeviseMailer class
- setting `default_url_options` in application_controller not necessary
- url_for is uncalled for

First element of answer:  get the routing established correctly:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { passwords: 'users/passwords' }
```

Second element of solution (preliminary - works in development on remote server), modify the devise passwords controller.

```
def create
   ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = params[:user][:host]
   super
end
```